# gs://<your-cloud-storage-bucket> has no CORS configuration

Tags: firebase, cors, firebase-storage

I am trying to download file from my firebase storage on button click event but it is giving me 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files

As per above link I am trying to configure CORS. I installed the gsutil command line tool. But I am unable to find cors.json file where I need to copy this code

```
[
 {
 "origin": ["*"],
 "method": ["GET"],
 "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
 }
]
```

I then used command `gsutil cors get gs://<your-cloud-storage-bucket>` which returns `gsutil cors get gs://<your-cloud-storage-bucket>/ has no CORS configuration`.

Do I need to create CORS configuration file for my storage bucket first ?

Below is my button click method, incase the error is in the code.

```
downloadAttachment(fileName) {
var uid = AuthService.uid;
let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref().child('assignments/' + uid + '/' + fileName);
storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
  console.log(url);
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.onload = function (event) {
    var blob = xhr.response;
  };
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.send();
});
}
```

Error :

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, create a file named anything you want—call it `cors.json` if you want—and put your preferred CORS config settings in it, and then run `gsutil` on it like this:

```
gsutil cors set cors.json gs://<your-cloud-storage-bucket>/
```

That will upload those CORS config settings to your bucket. And after that you can retrieve the current settings at any time using `gsutil cors get gs://<your-cloud-storage-bucket>`.

Comment: where should i save this `cors.json` file ?

Comment: You don’t necessarily need to save the cors.json file anywhere once you’ve called gsutil on it. You can if you want, and just save it on your PC wherever you want—e.g., in your home directory on your PC. But anyway once you’ve run 'gsutil cors set' with it the first time, after that you can get the current CORS config settings with 'gsutil cors get' at any time. So if you want to modify or add to the settings again later, you can just take the output of 'gsutil cors get' , copy it to a new file, add your changes, then call 'gsutil cors set'  on that new file.

Comment: i used this command  `gsutil cors set cors-json-file C:\Users\Prashant\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\cors.json` . It returns `CommandException: "cors" command does not support "file://" URLs. Did you mean to use a gs:// URL?`

Comment: You’re using the wrong command syntax. You don’t need the 'cors-json-file' part. You just need to give it an actual filename and your bucket with 'gs://<your-cloud-storage-bucket>/' , which it appears you’re not doing at all. Please use the command syntax in the answer. So, 'gsutil cors set C:\Users\Prashant\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\cors.json gs://<your-cloud-storage-bucket>/'. Or else just change to the 'C:\Users\Prashant\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\' directory and simply run 'gsutil cors set cors.json gs://<your-cloud-storage-bucket>/'.

Comment: What if the storagebucket has no "gs://" in its url. The configuration in the new version has no "gs://" ... if I try going gsutil cors set cors.json my_url_for_storage_bucket it doesn't work.

Comment: @sideshowbarker I am doing the exactly you are saying `gsutil cors set /Users/rea/Desktop/cors.json gs://example.appspot.com/`, but it keep saying `-bash: gsutil: command not found` and my `cors.json` is on my desktop with required information inside it. What I am missing here? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Simply run the command

```
gsutil cors set cors.json gs://<your-cloud-storage-bucket>
```

from the directory that contains the cors.json file.

Comment: Downvote as this is the same answer as already given four years ago.